# Is there a way in rails 3 to redirect any Internet Explorer user to specific page?

Tags: internet-explorer, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, routes

I want to redirect all IE users to a specific page that tells them we don't support IE and that they should try another browser. How can I do this using rails 3 routes and still allow public users to view the public area of the site?

My routes are something like this...

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  constraints(NoSubdomain) do
    root :to => 'public#index'
  end

  constraints(Subdomain) do
    root :to => 'internal#index'
  end
end
```

I know there is the ability to match `user_agent` but i'm not able to get it to redirect all ie users who try to go to the internal part of the site (account.myapp.com) to `'/ie'` page. Any ideas?

```
MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  constraints(NoSubdomain) do
    root :to => 'public#index'
  end

  constraints :user_agent => /MSIE/ do
    match "*" => redirect('/ie')
  end

  constraints(Subdomain) do
    root :to => 'internal#index'
  end
end
```

Comment: How about actually making things work in IE? I can understand not supporting IE6 and below, but come on... Anyway, browser detection is done with the user agent, which in the case of IE is identfiable by the substring MSIE.

Comment: +1 for rejecting IE users!! Hang them!! Set them on fire!!

Answer (score 0):

There seem to be two problems here.

First, you're calling redirect when matching everything.  So, the user requests account.myapp.com/ and that matches anything so they get redirected to account.myapp.com/ie, but that also matches anything and so they get redirected to account.myapp.com/ie and they get redirected again.  It becomes an infinite loop, but you probably didn't see this because Rails wouldn't even match it due to the second thing.

Second, Rails requires you to put a name in there.  You can use "*url" or whatever you like (path, page, whatever).  That's so that Rails can assign the requested path to that name in params - so that you get params[:url] with whatever the path is.  I was a little surprised that it wouldn't let you just use "*", but it doesn't.

This works for me:

```
constraints :user_agent => /Firefox/ do
  match "*url", :to => "ie#index"
end
```

I'm on a Mac and don't have IE to test with, but you can easily sub IE into there.